# Public key for mysql-community-client-5.6.40-2.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed. How to fix?

Tags: mysql, rhel7

I'm getting this error:

```
Downloading packages:
warning: /tmp/mysql-community-client-5.6.40-2.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY


Public key for mysql-community-client-5.6.40-2.el6.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by:

1. going to Mysql page and get the Cert and exporting into a text file
2. importing into the server with the command:  rpm --import /tmp/key.txt
3. running again the installation

> Installed:   mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el6
>   mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el6
>   mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el6
>   mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.6.40-2.el6
>
> Complete!